# Card Cannot Be Resolved To A Type Error

Tags: java

I created a class where I need to make an object for every single card in a video game.

For some reason I am getting a Card cannot be resolved to a type error.

Here is my code:

```
public class Cards {
  static void Card(String name, String rarity, String type){};
  Card Arrows = new Card("Arrows", "Common", "Spell");
}
```

Please help!

Thanks!

EDIT:
I meant to make this a method.
The code that REALLY isn't working is this:

```
public class Cards{
public static void CardDeclaration(){
          //Object Declaration
          Card(String name, String rarity, String type){};
          //Arrows Declaration
          Card Arrows = new Card("Arrows", "Common", "Spell");
    }
}
```

Now I get multiple errors.

First, I get, "String cannot be resolved to a variable"
Then I get, "Syntax error on token "name", delete this token (I get this with rarity and type as well.
Last, I get "Card cannot be resolved to a type"

Please help!

Comment: Java doesn't support `static` constructors

Comment: remove **static void** to define constructor of Card class

Comment: You've also never defined the class `Card` by the looks of things.

Comment: Check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html on how to write constructors.

Comment: Did @Glen Pierce answer helped ?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more like what you're looking for.

```
public class Card {
  String name;
  String rarity;
  String type;
  Card(String name, String rarity, String type){
      this.name = name;
      this.rarity = rarity;
      this.type = type;
  };

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Card arrows = new Card("Arrows", "Common", "Spell");
  }
}
```